# htaccess redirection not working and apply last rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've got a pb with my htaccess. 
Every pages are redirected to url.php even if i add rules before the last one.
Here is my htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule \.css - [L]
RewriteRule \.js - [L]

RewriteRule site - [L]
RewriteRule download.php - [L]
RewriteRule show_image.php - [L]
RewriteRule css_loader.php - [L]
RewriteRule js_loader.php - [L]
RewriteRule phpmailer.php - [L]
RewriteRule robots.txt - [L]

RewriteRule old - [L]


RewriteRule \.(png|gif|mpg|mpeg|jpg|pdf|doc|rtf|ico) - [L]

RewriteRule cron - [L]
RewriteRule generator - [L]
RewriteRule panneau - [L]
RewriteRule vertical - [L]
RewriteRule language_a.php - [L]
RewriteRule vaccin_a.php - [L]
RewriteRule faq_category.php - [L]
RewriteRule static.php - [L]
RewriteRule card_a.php - [L]


RewriteRule ckeditor - [L]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=2&&ss=3^ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=302]


RewriteRule ^content/card_a.php$  /content/card_a.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ url.php
```

When i want to go to http://mysite/content/card_a.php it redirect to url.php.
Any ideas ?

Thks
vince

Answer (score 1):

> Try like that for some RewriteRule to redirect

```
RewriteRule download.php$ download.php
RewriteRule show_image.php$ show_image.php
RewriteRule css_loader.php$ css_loader.php
RewriteRule js_loader.php$ js_loader.php
RewriteRule phpmailer.php$ phpmailer.php
RewriteRule robots.txt$ robots.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you describe has the symptoms of files not being found.

1. Does `content/card_a.php exist`? Is it returned by the server even
   if you temporarily rename the `.htaccess` file?
2. Does your servers configured `404` page work?

If not then the combination of missing files would cause the rules in your .htaccess file to return url.php to the client. This could be confirmed by checking to see if the response header was 404 instead of 200.